# Why doesn't copying values from MapInfo info tool boxes work properly?

Tags: mapinfo

As above. When I press ctrl + c, it doesn't always copy the value, I usually end up pressing ctrl + c 5 times to ensure it copies. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What version of MI Pro are you using, Alan? I think we fixed this at some point

Comment: I'm using version 10.5

Comment: Alan, tried finding exactly when we fixed the bug. Only thing I have found so far is that it was fixed some time after december 2010. This would probably mean that it was fixes in v11. I'll try tomorrow when I get back to work to find a more specific version for you

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that the problem seemed to be that it took MapInfo Pro a bit too long to get ready for copying. So if you wait a while before using Ctrl+C it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select some text it does take a while before the Copy / Cut tools recognise this.
This means that you'll have to wait until the Copy / Cut tools get enabled before you can use them or the Ctrl + C /Ctrl + X keyboard shortcut.

This issue was fixed with MapInfo Professional 11.0.